# Deploy a mobile flutter app on google play as production

Tags: flutter, google-play, google-play-console

I'm trying to deploy the app on the google play store, and I was wondering if I did that correctly. I have deployed the app as beta testing last week, and today I just uploaded to google play as production mode. I created new app bundle by running "flutter build appbundle" in my project, and put that generated file into the production track.

So far my google play console is something looks like this

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

On the picture #3, I can see the rollout history as full rollout, but in side of the production I can also see something says you have a release in produciton that hasn't been rolled out.

Does that mean I just need to wait the app reviewed? or deactivate previous app bundle and do something else?

Answer (score 0):

That looks correct. I just recently deployed an app to Android and it took over a week, maybe 2. I also noticed that that view isn't the most clear and descriptive. If you go to the Dashboard view you'll see all your apps and see the Status column. It'll say `Published` when it's live.